# Get page blank in submit form in php after changed server

Tags: ubuntu, php, wordpress

I have moved my server data PHP + Wordpress and database(mysql) from one server to another server... All things working fine... but some time i got page blank in click submit button.. This problem occures some time ..

I didnt get any error or fatal error in errorLog file and not get access entry in accsessLog file also on time of blank page.. Black page issue occurs some time on same task

So how can I fix this problem..

Answer (score 3):

A blank page from PHP usually indicates either a syntax error (unlikely if the page works intermittently) or a fatal error. You get a blank page because the option to 'DisplayErrors' is switched off in your webserver configuration.

I'd suggest your first point of call is to view the ErrorLogs on the server whilst viewing the page and trying to generate the 'blank page' - this should then present an error message in your log files.

Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew, I didnt get any error or fatal error in errorLog file and not get access entry in accsessLog file also on time of blank page.. Black page issue occurs some time on same task.. sorry i forgot to mentioned this point on my question..